# Is there a better alternative to eval() for my function checking algorithm

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval, jquery-mask

I have the following code below designed to check that a function exists at anytime.  **This code does not have any errors currently**.  I'm using this because my javascript files load in arbitrary orders and is necessary for my project its done that way.  Since my javascript files are separated in order to run functions between them you have to store them in a global variable and then call that function from the global variable.

**Example of Javascript File: "checker.js" // This checks if the function exists**!

```
       var funcList = {};
       $(document).ready(function(){
            funcList.requireJS =
            function requireJS(requires,callback){
                console.log("requireJS Starting With Requires Below:");
                console.log(requires);
                var attempts = 0;

                attemptRequire();

                function attemptRequire(){
                    $.each(requires, function (key, value){
                        attempts++;
                        console.log("Checking:"+value+" attempts="+attempts);
                        if (typeof eval(value) !== 'undefined'){
                            callback(); //them run the function
                        }else{
                            console.log("require JS waiting...");
                            setTimeout(function(){attemptRequire();}, 100);//wait and try again every 100 milliseconds.
                        }
                    });
                }

                console.log("requireJS Finished!...");
            };
        });
```

**Example of using global function: sample.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("Quote.Js Loading...");

    requires = {
        0 : "$.fn.mask"
    };

    funcList["requireJS"](requires, function(){
        $("#partone_phone").mask("(999) 999-9999? x99999");
        console.log("Quote.Js Loaded!");
    });

});
```

The idea is that if the plugin for 'masking' on jQuery has not loaded yet then it will not attempt to run the code but once it is loaded it will.  Attempting to run .mask when the plugin is not loaded will cause the fields to not have the affect desired.  I'm using jquery.mask as an example, but this could apply to anything.

I'm using jquery.mask however, because as a jquery function it seems the **only way to reference it is with $.fn.mask**

Typically I can test functions by saying **`typeof functionNameHere !== 'undefined'`** and this works, but since this is a jquery function if I send the string '$.fn.mask' it doesn't work unless I put an eval() around it... which as we all know is bad form!

**Does anyone have a better alternative to using eval() to make this work?**

Also Note:

```
requires = {
        0 : $.fn.mask
    };
```

Trying to send the function directly without strings does not work, because if it's undefined it stays undefined by the time it goes to requireJS.

Comment: pass executable functions instead.

Comment: wow, I've never gotten so many downvotes for a question...I'm about ready to remove it to save reputation, I wish I knew what I was doing wrong rules wise, this should be an okay question to ask and I'm not telling people to use eval.  As for Kevin B's response, I can't pass executable functions, that is the problem, at least with the way I have this designed.

Comment: By executeable functions, i mean: `0: function () {return $ && $.fn && $.fn.mask;}` now all you have to do is execute that function to see if `$.fn.mask` is defined yet.

Comment: oh I see, that is clever... hmm, let me try that.

Comment: Great answer Kevin it worked! :).  Put that as the answer and I can accept it :).  I never thought about sending a function result that could be checked, very smart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better alternative may be to just pass a function to be executed instead that returns the method you are looking for or false.

```
requires = {
    0 : function () {
        return $ && $.fn && $.fn.mask;
    }
};
```

Now, all you have to do is call `requires[0]()` to see if `$.fn.mask` is defined.

---

Side note: referencing this as "requireJS" might be confusing to future developers since this isn't [requireJS](http://requirejs.org/), it's just your own function for checking if a script is done loading. requireJS is a module loader that would likely make this problem less of a problem if you used it.

Comment: duly noted, I'll give it a different name.

Answer (score 0):

An excellent alternative to this is to define functions before using them.

For example:

```
function foo() {}

foo()
```

If you're loading scripts, make sure the  tag defining the plugin is above the one using it:

```
<script src="/yet/another/jquery/plugin.js"></script>
<script src="/my/code.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just pass the function itself?

Since you're `eval`ing the passed name, these functions are in the global scope and you have very little interest in the context under which they're called.

Rather than passing a name and assuming they will be accessible, just pass a reference to the function and call that. It will make your design *much* more flexible.

```
requires = {
  0 : $.fn.mask
};
```

and

```
if (value() !== 'undefined') {
  callback(); //them run the function
```

If you need to control the execution context of the functions, use `bind` before you pass them in:

```
requires = {
  0: $.fn.mask.bind($),
  1: console.log.bind(console)
};
```

The [`bind` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) allows you to prepare a function with a given scope and some arguments.

Comment: passing the function itself can also cause it to lose context. for example, if you passed console.log, it loses the `console` context. In your example, it loses $.fn.

Comment: so use .bind to force the context. `console.log.bind(console)`

Comment: If you care about the scope, pass a bound version of the function: `console.log.bind(console)`

Comment: That should be part of the answer, considering the OP has already tried what you're suggesting in the answer. (bind of course fixes that issue)

Comment: I tried this, does not work because if it's undefined it stays undefined by the time it goes to requireJS and starts the looping process, this is why it needed to be a string.

Comment: Then you need to require the validators/callbacks from within or before you pass them.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, recently the answer I accepted has created lots of random javascript errors which would occur and they would not report errors to the console.

I've made a new algorithm which seems to be more reliable, but does depend upon eval() still..., but at least it works.

I am not claiming this to be a good answer, but it does work for me, maybe it will work for someone else.

```
 var funcList = {};
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //Because javascript files are loaded asynchronously, use requireJS to ensure javascript is loaded...
    //...for your modules to prevent errors.  To load this function from anyfile use the funcList global var.
    //Helper function to get REAL type since mobile safari has issues
    var toType = function(obj) {
        return ({}).toString.call(obj).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase()
    }

    funcList.requireJS =
    function requireJS(requires,callback){
        console.log("requireJS Starting With Requires Below****:");
        console.log(requires);
        var attempts = 0;
        var successcount = 0;

        attemptRequire();

        function attemptRequire(){
            successcount = 0;//reset it to 0
            $.each(requires, function (key, value){
                attempts++;
                console.log("Checking*:"+value+" attempts="+attempts);

                var type = '';

                var errorOccured = false;
                try{
                    console.log("trying...");
                    type = toType(eval(value));
                    console.log("type="+type);
                    if(type=="function"){
                        successcount++;
                        attempts--;
                        errorOccured = false;
                    }else{
                        console.log("throwing...");
                        throw "Custom error message: Function is undefined, must be defined as function";
                    }
                }
                catch (err){
                    errorOccured = true;
                    console.log("catching...");
                    console.log("error="+err.message);
                }
                finally {
                    if(errorOccured == true){
                        console.log("JS For "+value+" Not Ready Yet, Trying Again in 100ms");
                        setTimeout(function(){attemptRequire();}, 100);//wait and try again every 100 milliseconds.
                        return false;//exit the entire foreach loop early~
                    }
                }
            });
            //Only call the callback once if all requires came in correctly.
            if(successcount == Object.keys(requires).length){
                console.log("calling callback...");
                callback(); //then run the function
            }
        }

        console.log("End of requireJS Function Call");
    };
    console.log("includes.js loaded");
});
```

Modify the console.log's in this if you want and it should be ready to go.  To call it here is a sample below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    requires = {
        0 : '$.fn.mask',
        1 : '$.fn.validate',
        2 : 'google.maps.LatLng'
    };

    funcList["requireJS"](requires, function(){
        //code dependent upon mask and validate here!
    });
});
```